# there exists a bipartite graph whose size $\geq \frac{m}{2}$

Tags: graph-theory

The question I am trying to solve now is "Prove that every graph $G$ has a bipartite subgraph of size $\geq \frac{m}{2}$" by using a probability method (defining a sample space and a random variable).

I wonder if my answer below is right, so I would appreciate it if you can check it.

1) Define a sample space $\Omega$ = {the set of all possible bipartite subgraphs $V_1 \bigsqcup V_2$ of $G$}.

2) Define a random variable $X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that for $V_1 \bigsqcup V_2 \in \Omega$, $X(V_1 \bigsqcup V_2)$ is the number of edges of $V_1 \bigsqcup V_2$. Also, $X= \sum^m_{i=1}Y_i$ where $Y_i$ is the indicator of the existence of the edge $e_i$ in $V_1 \bigsqcup V_2$. By definition of $X$, $\forall V_1 \bigsqcup V_2 \in \Omega$, the maximum size of a bipartite subgraph $\geq X(V_1 \bigsqcup V_2)$.

3) The expected value $E(X) = \sum^m_{i=1} E(Y_i) = \sum^m_{i=1} P(e_i \in V_1 \bigsqcup V_2) = \sum^m_{i=1} \frac{1}{2} = \frac{m}{2}$. For every $i$, $P(e_i \in V_1 \bigsqcup V_2) = \frac{1}{2}$ because $e_i$ is either "in $V_1 \bigsqcup V_2$" or "not."

Thank you in advance!

Comment: To confirm this explicitly: yes, your solution is essentially correct (modulo the important detail of why the probability is $\frac12$), and Mike's answer below is the common informal way of writing up this argument. (Note that choosing uniformly for each vertex $v$ whether $v \in V_1$ or $v \in V_2$ is equivalent to choosing one of the $2^n$ ordered bipartitions $V_1 \sqcup V_2$ uniformly at random.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am having a tough time following your notation, OP. I am not positive if you meant it this way or not, but not every bipartite subgraph of $G$ is in the set $\Omega$ as you defined in 1).

This is how I would approach this problem: Partition randomly $V(G)$ into two sets $V_1$ and $V_2$ as follows. For each vertex $v$ flip a fair coin: Heads vertex $v$ goes into $V_1$; tails $v$ goes into $V_2$. Now from this partition of $V(G)$ into $V_1$ and $V_2$, we create a subgraph $G_B$ of $G$ that is necessarily bipartite, with parts $V_1$ and $V_2$. For each edge $uv \in E(G)$, the edge $uv$ is also in $G_B$ iff either $u$ is put into $V_1$ and $v$ into $V_2$, or $u$ is put into $V_2$ and $v$ into $V_1$.

Then for each $e \in E(G)$ the probability that the partitioning of $V(G)$ into $V_1$ and $V_2$ is such that edge $e$ is also in $G_B$ is precsisely $\frac{1}{2}$. Can you finish from here.

Comment: I also think the notation is cumbersome because in practice nobody writes out the probability space and a random variable as a function on it. But this is not OP's fault!  The question asks for that notation. (And, admittedly, when you are just starting out working with random variables, it's worth writing out the details so that later, when you skip the details, you at least know what they are.)

Comment: @MishaLavrov  well, the issue that I had was really with 1) in the OP's post. Was $\Omega$ really $\{G_{V_1}; V_1$ a subset of $V(G)$, where the graph $G_{V_1}$ is defined as follows: $e \in E(G_1)$ iff $e \in G$ and exactly one endpoint of $e$ is in $V_1\}$? Or was $\Omega$ instead the set of **all bipartite subgraphs** of $G$? I **think** the OP meant the former but I am not positive. I had to reread a few times. These are indeed different definitions for $\Omega$, and so I think the other answer given has a point. I should have made that clear in my answer in the first place.

Comment: Oh, I see your point now. The way I would phrase it is "the set of all bipartitions of $V(G)$" but the terminology around bipartite graphs is so awkward that I'm not surprised the OP was confused.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that your reasoning is valid. The fact that $e_i$ is either "in $V_1\cup V_2$" or "not" does not implies that the probability that the edge is in is one-half. Taking another (more simple) example, the edge $e_i$ is either connected to all other edgess, or "is not". But the probability that the edge is connected to all other edges is clearly not one-half.

If you were looking at $\Omega$ the set of all subgraph of $G$, then yes you would have $E(X)=1/2$ : in all subgraphs of $G$, there is an unique 1-to-1 correspondance between graphs including $e_i$ and not including $e_i$. But here, with $\Omega$ the set of all possible bipartite subgraphs, this is not the case for any graph $G$.

For instance lets define $G = K_3$ the complete graph on 3 labelled vertices. It has 7 bipartite subgprahs (3 with 2 edges, 3 with 1 edges and one with no edges). Then for every edge $P(e_i \in V_1\cup V_2)=3/7$.

Comment: Well, I think this is what the OP did: Take a bipartition $V_1,V_2$ of $V$, and then after $V_1$ and $V_2$ is taken, then count every edge between $V_1$ and $V_2$. This is different from taking the expected value of the number of edges in a bipartite subgraph of $G$. Indeed for the instance where $G=K_3$ on labelled vertices the resulting bipartite subgraph will either have two edges ($V_1$ and $V_2$ both nonempty) or none. That said the OP's notation was hard to follow.